# JQuery Read text from a specific child DIV by Class

Tags: jquery

I know the ID of one of my DIV's, I want to search until I find a child DIV of a specific class and read the text from it..

I will also need to update the text within that same DIV.

[image]

The ID is `4` and the DIV I want the text from is `flowchart-operator-connector-label`

I've tried :

```
$('#4').find('.flowchart-operator-connector-label').text()
$('#4').closest('.flowchart-operator-connector-label').text() 
$('#4').children('.flowchart-operator-connector-label').text()
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

One crucial item I should have mentioned is the element is being dynamical created.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: why don't you post the node as text and you posted this image??

Comment: Can you have just a number as an ID? I don't think that works.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan you can in html 5, you just need to watch out if you try use it in css

Comment: does any of that queries work when you use them in the console? if yes then you execute your script before the element is loaded to the dom.

Comment: @Tom please don't post pictures of code, post actual code in a [mcve] - please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: One crucial item I should have mentioned is the element is being dynamical created and I'm trying to find the value then.. Sorry I should have said that in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
$('#4 div').find('.flowchart-operator-connector-label').text();
```

With `$('#4 div')` you have all the `div` child and then you can find it.

Comment: find doesn't filter, it finds elements matching the selector below the elements returned from the previous selector.  I don't see how this is any different to the original code apart from you will have more elements returned from the first part of the selector

Comment: @Pete sorry for my english.

Comment: This works when run form the console, just not when run from my page..  One crucial item I should have mentioned is the element is being dynamical created.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would specify the path more precisely. By this I mean

```
.flowchart-operator-connector .flowchart-operator-connector-label
```

This might not solve your problem but it is more readable and might help you further on in your project.

I would also try searching for child elements like so:

```
.flowchart-operator > .flowchart-operator-connector-label
```

Also, it would have helped if you posted your output. I am going off luck here :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#4 .flowchart-operator-connector-label').text()
```

or if you want to make it general:

```
let id = 4;
let text = $(`#${id} .flowchart-operator-connector-label`).text();
```

Comment: Same issue as the other.. doesn't work when the element is being dynamically created.